# complement of a set and its measure

Tags: measure-theory

if $E = [0,1] \bigcap \mathbb{Q} $, what is $E^\complement$  with respect to $[0,1]$ and its outer measure $m^\ast(E^\complement)$?

The outer measure is defined thus:

$m^\ast(E^\complement):= \inf_P m(P)$

where $P$ ranges over the set of multi-intervals containing $E$: $E \subseteq P$

Comment: Use the properties of $m^\ast$, not its definition. "multi-intervals" is not a standard term, you mean at most countable union of intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E^\complement = \{x \in [0,1]: x \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$, the irrational points of $[0,1]$, when we take the complement in $[0,1]$, as $E$ consists of the rational points (so is countable and hence has $m^\ast(E)=0$).

$m^\ast(E^\complement)=1$ as is easy to see. Note that subadditivity and monotonicity of $m^\ast$ already tell us that

$$1=m^\ast([0,1]) \le m^\ast(E) + m^\ast(E^\complement) = 0 + m^\ast(E^\complement)= m^\ast(E^\complement) \le m^\ast([0,1])=1$$

Comment: I tried to use De Morgan's Law: The complement of an intersection is the union of complements $\left(A\cap B\right)^{c}=A^{c}\cup B^{c}$ which in this case should be: $[0,1]^c \cup \mathbb{Q}^C =\emptyset \cup [0,1]$ but it is wrong

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta inside $[0,1]$ the complement of $[0,1]$ is $\emptyset$, indeed but the complement of the rationals (even inside $[0,1]$) is not $[0,1]$, but like I said, the irationals in that interval.

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta It's formulaic expression is unimportant for the computation ofits outer measure. I don't use it. Just that $E$ is countable and thus has outer measure $0$; that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

The outer measure is clearly less than or equal to $1$. Suppose $m^{*}(E^{c}) =r<1$. Cover the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ by intervals with total length $t <1-r$ and cover $E$ by intervals with total length less than $r$. Putting these together we can cover $[0,1]$ by intervals with total length $t+r <1$ which contradicts the fact that measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$. Hence $m^{*}(E^{c})=1$

Comment: What is the expression for $E^c$ ?

Comment: $E^{c}=[0,1]\setminus E$ the set of all irrational numbers in $[0,1]$.

Comment: if $E^c$ is an irrational set why are you talking of covering the rationals in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta The idea is to cover both $E$ and $E^{c}$ to get a cover for $[0,1]$ with total length less than $1$.